# Access value based on value of other key in object?

Tags: handlebars.js

This is (hopefully) a simple solution but I cannot figure it out.

I have an array of objects and I need to access a value by specifying the value of another key.

[{ category_id: 14, description: 'AMAZON DIGITAL' },
 { category_id: 15, description: 'AMAZON DIGITAL SER' }]

Basically, I want to get "AMAZON DIGITAL" when the category_id is 14. Ideally, without using a loop.

Comment: My first inclination is to ask you whether an Object might be more suitable to your purpose than an Array?

Comment: It's an array of objects

Comment: I see that. But why not an Object of Objects? If you don't want to loop over the Array, I don't see the purpose of it.